# mapboxgl-js How to remove Mapbox wordmark?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Wordmark is very annoying especially when putting a map inside another map using sync, then get double wordmarks.

Is there a hacking way to remove wordmark without contacting sales@mapbox?

https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-attribution-works/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attribution control can be disabled when the map is instantiated in the options.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/bright-v9',
    attributionControl: false
});
```

Please remember to always observe the correct attribution requirements in the link you posted.

Comment: attribution is gone by setting that, but the wordmarks are still there. There is a logoPosition attribute, but it seems to not control that.

Answer (score 0):

src/ui/map.js

A hacking way, add a new option **logoControl** and just if wrap like the the attibutionControl.

```
if (options.attributionControl) this.addControl(new AttributionControl());
this.addControl(new LogoControl(), options.logoPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

To respect the watermark / attribution copyright requirements, but move it to a more convenient location, you can compromise by setting its location.
When the map is initialized, use `logoPosition: 'bottom-right'` ... or another corner.